# Count rows from left table without corresponding value in the right table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to count rows from left table (of a 1-to-many relation between two tables) that do not have PK-FK representative in right table

Left table

```
id | value
-----------
1  |  a
2  |  b
3  |  c
```

Right table

```
id | id-left | value
--------------------
.. |  1      | ....
```

the expected result is 2 as rows with id `1` and `3` in left table have no counterpart in right table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *not exists* anti-semi-join:

```
select count(*)
from l
where not exists (
  select * from r where r.id_left = l.id
);
```

Comment: Yes it works thank you! Do you know if this solution is recommended over eg `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM left l LEFT JOIN right r ON l.id=r.id_left WHERE r.id_left IS NULL` ??

Comment: Yes, I would recommend using *exists* over an outer join if you don't need data from the joined table as the optimizer does not have to join all rows.